# Unity Scene rotation arrows went missing suddenly

Tags: unity-game-engine

How to enable the one that allows me to rotate the scene during development in unity (Scene Gizmo), which is the one located at the top right of the scene. That one suddenly disappears when I click onto it to change the position of the view but it have been working fine all along until now. Could someone please tell me fix this?

thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh i had found a way,  I press "Add Tab" followed by "Scene:, the Arrows appears again YAY

Answer (score 10):

Press "W" to make the arrows come back: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PositioningGameObjects.html

Answer (score 1):

Right click on Scene tab. Hover over Overlays and check Orientation.

Answer (score 0):

W = arrows (for position transform) E = sphere (for rotation transform) R = blocks (for scaling transform)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Got editor bug with the arrows (move/rotation) disappear. (not the first time, 8 years experience with unity)

Some of these steps should help:

1. Press W/E (also F few times to focus object root)
2. Click Add Tab -> Scene (on Game tab header)
3. Switch to 2D view and back
4. If you using ProBuilder, be sure to be in object mode, otherwise controls be hidden
5. Try change editor layout in Window->Layouts
6. The final. You need to call the code from editor script: **UnityEditor.Tools.hidden = false;**

Answer (score 0):

If *all* of the scene overlays have vanished, try pressing the backtick (<kbd>`</kbd>) key.